# Javascript API for Office - Inline Image with anchor

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm doing a Word Add-in using a VSTO Web Word template.

This add-in has to add a header and a footer in a word document, after clicking in the add-in button.

In this moment, i already can add a header and a footer in a word document pretty well, but, now, i need to positioning the image absolutely in the left and in the top with 100% width, independently of the document margin.

Somebody cann show or indicate me some way to positioning this image like I need?

> **Here follow the code to put the image in the header:
>   **

```
 var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary");
        myHeader.clear();
        var img = myHeader.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(imgHeader, Word.InsertLocation.start);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Diego, I’m having trouble understanding your question. Could you please edit it and make it clearer?

Comment: @Sasha, It's better now?

Comment: It's not possible to freely position an inline picture on the page. The current Word JS API does not have an option to insert pictures with text wrap formatting. Possibly, it could be done by inserting the content as Office Open XML (insertOoxml)...

Comment: @CindyMeister, Interesting...

Could you giveme one example like a answer, here? I will search about it, but this example would help me a lot..

Comment: @DiegoSantos You had any luck with this? I tried some ooxml implementations but sadly, all seem to fail with a GeneralException error. It seems that even in the current API version of officejs, there is still no easy way to control the image, e.g. setting its position or setting it behind text.

Comment: Six years since the question was asked, Office.js API still has no way of freely poisitioning pictures, or doing almost anything with Shapes. And yet they want everyone to switch from VBA and VSTO to Office.js. Hello Microsoft!